# Horizontal and Vertical alignment of images

Tags: floats, formatting, subfloats

I'm using the acm latex template for journals available here: http://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions

This follows a one-column format. Now I have 8 images, which I want to be displayed with captions in the following pattern:

[image]

I don't know how to get this format using subfigure or any other way.

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title[This is a Title]{This is a title}  
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pam}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{jam}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

.
.
.
.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `subcaption` package, a `subfigure` environment *is* a `minipage` environment, with the added capability of processing `\caption` and `\label` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, 
               screen=true, demo]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array,varwidth,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Chow, Dow, and Pow}  
\author{Mr. T and the A-Team}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4] % filler text

\begin{figure}[tp!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figa}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figb}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figc}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figd}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fige}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figf}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figg}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figh}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Overall figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-12] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false,
               screen=true, demo]{acmart}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array,varwidth,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Chow, Dow, and Pow}
\author{Mr. T and the A-Team}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4] % filler text

\begin{figure}[tp!]
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\linewidth]{figa}}%
    \hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figb}}

\medskip
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figc}}%
    \hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figd}}

\medskip
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{fige}}%
    \hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figf}}

\medskip
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figg}}%
    \hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figh}}

\caption{Overall figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-12] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
added `%` for terminate the lines of code for the four left-hand images (as suggested  [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in his comment below).

Comment: @Mico, thank you! i add `%` (in hope that ones i earning David Carlisle stamp :-) ...).  why is now "extra-safe". do the space before `\hfill` hazardous? this is new to me. and +1 for your answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I made pairs of 2 images in the following way:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{imgs/gmail_spam/spam_spam}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{imgs/gmail_spam/spam_phishing}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
...
```

And repeated 4 times. This gave the desired formatting.

Please let me know if there's an alternative solution.